# What is the correct way to use wow.js in Rails 6 with webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, wow.js

I am trying to use [wow.js](https://github.com/graingert/wow) with my Ruby on Rails 6.1.3.2 project. I have installed wowjs with Yarn and I see it in my node_modules folder.

I have imported wowjs into my application app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import WOW from 'wowjs';
require("wowjs/css/libs/animate.css")
```

I have a script.js file located at this path: app/javascript/script.js and initiates WOW

```
    wow = new WOW({
        animateClass: 'animated',
        offset: 100
    });
    wow.init();
```

script.js is imported into app/javascript/packs/application.rb after wowjs is imported like this:

```
import WOW from 'wowjs';
require("wowjs/css/libs/animate.css")
import "scripts.js"
```

I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
scripts.js:514 Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (scripts.js:514)
at Object../app/javascript/scripts.js (scripts.js:897)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:63)
at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:63)
at bootstrap:198
at bootstrap:198
```

I have other modules that I have installed in a similar manner that are not throwing errors. I'd like to understand what the "rails way" of doing this is. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was ultimately the following:

Move the import statements from application.js to scripts.js where the modules were being used:

```
import "splitting/dist/splitting.css";
import "splitting/dist/splitting-cells.css";
import Splitting from "splitting";
```

I was missing the declaration of 'wow' as a 'var'. So I added 'var' to the script.js like this:

```
var wow = new WOW({
    animateClass: 'animated',
    offset: 100
});
wow.init();
```

The key lesson for me was that the import statements needed to be at the top of the script that was consuming the modules. I had assumed that just by virtue of them being imported into application.js that was enough to make them available to all scripts. Perhaps that was a newbie lesson. Many thanks to @rossta for some important guidance. I'm looking forward to his soon coming The Webpacker Course.

Answer (score 2):

Install jquery, wowjs by yarn, add this line to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
window.WOW = require('wowjs').WOW;
```

Embed wow css to project by add to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` this line:

```
 @import "wowjs/css/libs/animate";
```

And finish by create this view example `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`:

```
Welcome to project railstrace !
<section class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">ABC</section>
<section class="wow slideInRight" data-wow-offset="10"  data-wow-iteration="10">DEF</section>

<script>
  new WOW({live: false}).init()
</script>
```

Note: If set `new WOW({live: false}).init()` will remove this warning: MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I was also able to avoid asset pipeline by requiring the css in the application.js file by adding this line `require("wowjs/css/libs/animate.css")`